# How to shift an index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm still new to python and exploring pandas at the same time. So I created a dataframe in pandas to help me understand it better. So my dataframe is this:

```
   name    age   sex 
0  mike     20  male  
1        kelly    25  female
2         john    30    male
```

So how can I fix the dataframe for index 1 and 2? I have tried to code like this but it does not work. Can someone help me?

**My code**

```
x = range(0,3)
for n in x:
    df.iloc[1, n] = df.iloc[1, n + 1]
    print(df.iloc[1])
```

**The result**

```
name        25
age         25
sex     female
        female
Name: 1, dtype: object
name        25
age     female
        female
Name: 1, dtype: object
name        25
age     female
sex     female
        female
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
print (df)
   name    age   sex     col
0  mike     20  male     NaN
1   NaN  kelly    25  female
2   NaN   john    30    male
```

If possible after shifting per rows some columns are filled missing values reason is not matched dtypes, solution is convert columns to strings

```
#df = df.astype(str)
```

Use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) by all rows without first:

```
df.loc[1:] = df.loc[1:].shift(-1, axis=1)

print (df)
    name age     sex  col
0   mike  20    male  NaN
1  kelly  25  female  NaN
2   john  30    male  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you need, you can simply shift the rows by using the function of pandas `shift` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html))

```
df.loc[1:2].shift(periods=-1, axis='columns')
```